# Bindingsource: What events is raised to notify that a value is changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

My form has a BindingSource filled with objects that implement a certain interface. The datasource is set to this interface. These objects also implement INofityPropertyChanged.

The form also has a DataGridView that is connected to the BindingSource.

Whenever for any reason any property of any object in the BindingSource changes (not just editing a current cell in the DataGridView), the corresponding cell value in the datagridview is automatically updated.

This works fine if I want to show Booleans, numbers, texts and enums. If only the text or a checkbox of the property is displayed, they are automatically updated whenever the value changes - even if it is changed without editing the current cell in the DataGridView. So apparently the bindingsource raises an event telling the datagridview that a certain property of a certain object in the list of objects has changed.

If I want to show an image depending on the value of one of the properties (for instance enum), my form needs to subscribe to this event to update the image in the datagridview.

To be notified of these changes my form could subscribe to the INotifyChanged of all elements in the list of the bindingsource, but it seems that the needed event is already raised by the bindingsource itself

My question is: What event is raised by the BindingSource to notify that property X of element Y in the bindingsource list has changed?